# How many laptops are allowed in hand baggage in European flight?

Tags: air-travel, europe, hand-luggage, electronic-items, airbaltic

I am travelling from Riga to Stockholm with *AirBaltic* flight carrier. 
I only need my laptops: 11" Chromebook, 15" Lenovo Thinkpad, and 13" Asus Zenbook. 
The weight is not too much. They all can fit my backpack.

There are three batteries: two integrated (Chromebook and Asus), and one which can be deattached (Lenovo). 
I did not find any facts about the maximum amount of batteries allowed.

I also would like to take one iPad with me, one Pebble smart watch and one phone (Oneplus 2). I think the situation should be ok. So 6 batteries altogether, but 3 in laptops.

Comment: Be prepared to have a bunch of questions asked by security - they may want to know why you have so many more than most folks.

I had 5 identical laptops, plus sundry other devices one trip - and I had to explain what they were all for, and assure security I wasn't trying to just sell them.

Comment: chx - you got my upvote anyway :-)

Comment: sure - I'm using security to mean the uniformed folks who were asking the questions :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The small batteries inside devices are not a problem even if they removable.

[FAA FAQ](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ash/ash_programs/hazmat/passenger_info/media/airline_passengers_and_batteries.pdf) (lithium regulations are same everywhere):

> The main limit is that the batteries and devices must be for personal use (includes professional use). Batteries and
>   battery-powered devices carried for resale or for distribution by a vendor do not qualify for these exceptions. There is a two-spare
>   limit on the large lithium-ion (101-160 Wh) and nonspillable batteries.

[Elsewhere still FAA](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/hazmat_safety/more_info/?hazmat=7):

> Quantity limits: None for most batteries – but batteries must be for use by the passenger.

1. Security wise there's no limitation. My record so far has been three laptops, two phones, a tablet and an eReader, at Canadian, USA, UK and several Schengen airports. Noone gave a hoot.
2. Your only possible problem could be customs but you are intra Schengen so no such problems exist.

Edit: despite there is no customs, security might ask whether you plan to sell them because of the battery rule above. Have a simple, *true* explanation ready.

Comment: Schengen has nothing to do with customs. You may need to declare things whenever traveling to or from a non-EU country, even if your origin and destination are both in Schengen.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm reacting to "you are intra Schengen so no such problems exist", which is a non sequitur.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Er sorry - managed to _completely_ skip that part of the answer. Hah

Answer (score 3):

The company I work for does conference management and we often send staff onsite. As they usually use a few laptops for registration and paper upload work most of them have 2-3 laptops in their hand luggage. Flown to the US, Dubai, Turkey, all over the EU with laptops in hand luggage and normal luggage. No-one ever had a problem.

I once entered the US with a suitcase full of electronics (router, switches, cables, 3 laptops, small printers, print server, a few tablets, a small NUC computer) and flew back. Not a peep from any customs.

Ok, the laptops are obviously battered and used and we can show that we work onsite at a convention so obviously they are not for resale, but no-one has actually asked.